# Why sometime we see hashes such as md5 and sha256 when we download software?

Tags: security, encryption, md5, sha256

I know that is md5 and sha256 are hashing and authenticating mechanism, but I wonder why when I want to download some softwares I## Heading ## found them in front of my face :/

For example: if you want to download php package you will see

php-7.0.4.tar.bz2 (sig) [13,698Kb]

md5: 0171201350941327399a5c3e678a86e5

sha256: a246c503709c189ba8e1e22ed2cb22abc27da43a997ff1b3318e181baf529dcc

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 1):

The hashes are provided so the after download you can perform the same hash on the download to insure you have the correct and non-corrupted version.

This may be important if you obtain the download from another source.